# Page loads 1/5 down and then goes up to normal

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with my site: https://dolphin-healthcare.dk/kontakt/

When you load the page here it starts 1/5 down and then goes up. Do anyone know why it acts like this? I don't think it is a good user experience. I have tried to add a preloader but I don't think that is good user experience either.

Do anyone know a fix for this or what is causing the issue?

Comment: This isn't a website troubleshooting service. Please read through [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Check line 264 in this file:

https://dolphin-healthcare.dk/wp-content/themes/themify-ultra/style.css?ver=1.5.1

The `padding-top` property of `#pagewrap` is being set to 470 and is overwritten later by another css file.  This makes it appear to load further down on the page and then suddenly jump to the top.